# Which is correct 'once you have given to me' or 'once you give me'?

Tags: tense, phrase-choice

Shall I say

I will paypal **once you have given to me** the price for the book or
**once you give me** the price for the book.

Think both are correct.

Comment: The perfect tense focus in the present. (Because it's a *present* tense.) So either of those work.

Comment: I think in this case you should use the [present-simple](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html)

Answer (score 1):

Both alternatives are correct as pictured in this [ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=once+you+have+given%2Conce+you+give&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conce%20you%20have%20given%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conce%20you%20give%3B%2Cc0), but I, personally, would prefer the [simple present](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html) as the use refers to scheduled events in the near future.